# How do I make intellij Idea to highlight Scala script correctly with #! (shebang)

Tags: linux, scala, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, ammonite

How do I make intellij Idea to highlight Scala script correctly.

**Attempt 1**
change filename to *'test.sc'* . Intellij does not like the first line i.e it is not valid scala comment syntax

**Attempt 2**
change filename to *'test.sh'* . Intellij thinks all of the syntax is bash script.

filenName = ./test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env amm
import ammonite.ops._ , ImplicitWd._

println("Stop script")
val x = 1 + 1
```

Comment: We have an open issue for ammonite scripts: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10752

Answer (score 20):

If you need to preserve `.sc` extension here is a little trick

- change shebang to `#! /usr/bin/env amm` which is still a [valid shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276751/is-space-allowed-between-and-bin-bash-in-shebang/276845)
- put a file named `#!.scala` next to your script with the content:

```scala
class CLZ {
  def /(that: CLZ): CLZ = this
  def amm: Unit = {}
}
object #! extends CLZ
object usr extends CLZ
object bin extends CLZ
object env extends CLZ
```

Now, your script is properly highlighted

[image]

### Update

JetBrains published a [blog article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2018/05/07/ammonite-support/) about support for Ammonite.

Comment: `.sc` is also properly highlighted because is the extension used by Scala Worksheets, but 2 panes a shown.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `.scala` extension, IDEA recognizes as a valid Scala script file.
Even a multiline shebang line is supported:

```
#!/bin/sh
  DIR=$(cd `dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"` && pwd)
  exec scala -classpath $DIR/scalaj-http_2.11-2.3.0.jar -savecompiled "$0" "$@"
!#
/* Scala code*/
```

Make sure:

- you are using a relatively recent version of IDEA.
- Scala plugin is installed.
- The script lies in a Scala module.

It works even if the script is outside of a declared source folder.
I can even edit scripts outside of my project.